# Adding Quotes to List

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list which include Strings and it shows Strings in textview like `Item1 , Item2,Item3`, I want to add quotes on both side of each String and want this kind of output `"Item1" , "Item2 , "Item3"`

How to achieve the above type of list

Comment: add quotes to the content of your input..

Comment: Could you please show some attempt at what you've tried with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to append the quotes to the beginning and the end of your string. Here is an example:

```
public class QuotesDemo {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> correctItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addQuotes() {
        for (String i : items) {
            String newI = "\"" + i + "\"";
            correctItems.add(newI);
        }
    }
}
```